# How to repair an electronic igniter on a gas stove?

Tags: gas, stove

How can I repair an electing ignition on a gas stove that is intermittent?

Comment: Make and model?

Comment: Replace the igniter?

Comment: Are the electrodes clean? including the area on the burner it arcs to? buildup can be an insulator or sometimes a short reducing the arc.

Comment: There are several types of selectively ignition (piezo, mains/battery powered spam generator). Which do you have? Piezo normally has a dedicated button which you have to push quite firmly, and doesn't need a power source.

Answer (score 1):

You didn't specify what is the failure mode of the unit..!! Did you changed its battery? Assuming its using battery, check for corrosion at battery holder/contacts.

High voltage spark points may have carbon or any other residue which might shorting out the arc. If its using piezoelectric generator (battery not used) very likely it may have shorted path in its high voltage side causing intermittent operations.

Electronic type using battery and boost converter. Any failure in this sections requires knowledge in electronics in order to repair it.

Comment: Also, the burner's flame spreader should be removed and checked for alignment with the igniter.  If it is cockeyed, it limits the spark.